# Getting undefined error in object declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my object:

```
$scope.obj = {
        name: null,
        child: { name : name}
    };

<input type="text" ng-model="obj.name" />
```

What I am trying to do is when I will have latest value in my obj.name property it should automatically get reflected in obj.child.name property.

I would always like to use updated value and everywhere I am using obj.child.name property only so later on if I forgot to assign like below:

```
$scope.obj.child.name = $scope.obj.name
```

then it will always use old value and I don't want to do this at so many place. So I want this process to be automated like whenever name $scope.obj.name will be updated; it should automatically update $scope.obj.child.name.

But with above code I am getting error: **name is undefined**.

Why is the above declaration not possible and how to achieve this?

Comment: This won't work because there is no `name` variable in the given context. You can create a function and return the value of `name` from it. `child: function() { return this.name; }`.

Comment: @Tushar Can you provide this in the form of answer with some more details like explanation and how to use it.please

Comment: @Tushar But then will it be accessible like this if i follow your suggestion : $scope.obj.child.name ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting ***`name` is `undefined`*** because JavaScript is trying to find a `name` object in the global scope and can't find it, in this code:

```
child: { name : name//undefined}
```

This is how you can define it:

```
$scope.obj = {
   name: "Ay"
};
$scope.obj.child = {
  name: $scope.obj.name 
}
```

We will refer to the `$scope.obj.name` in the `child` property declaration here so it's correctly binded.

Comment: Ok upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but can i have something like this :child: function() { return this.name; } what @Tushar mention in this comment above if you can see

Comment: You can write like this too 

$scope.obj = {
        name: null,
        child: { name : $scope.obj.name }
    };

Comment: @Learning Yes you can define it like this `$scope.obj = {
    name: "Ay",
    child: 
      function() { return this.name;}
  };` but you won't have a `child.name` proprty, it will be just a function that returns the `name`of the `$scope.obj`.

Comment: @HamikHambardzumyan No you can't, it will fire an error: `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Comment: So when i will try to access $scope.obj.child.name i wont be able to access it?

Comment: Yes, if you follow the `child: function() { return this.name; }` suggestion, you won't be able to get `$scope.obj.child.name` as `child` is just a function.

Comment: Yes you are correct sir.it is then created as a function inside instead of property

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring obj wrong:

```
$scope obj = {
  name: null,
  child: { name : name}
};
```

Should be

```
$scope.obj = {
  name: null,
  child: { name : name}
};
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo mistake.i have updated my question but still the problem is same